# DBGrid Delphi Seattle

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

instalei um trial do Delphi Seattle e compilei meu sistema, mas percebi que ao abrir uma determinada consulta a coluna não fica com o tamanho que determinei anteriormente. Ao compilar no Delphi 7 as colunas ficam do tamanho correto.

Alguém mais esta passando por esse problema?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Até onde eu sei pela minha experiência o XE7, ele vai se ajustar ao conteúdo, e como não tem nada ele deixa num tamanho padrão. Pra forçar o tamanho dele eu não lembro se tem alguma configuração pra isso. Claro, você sempre pode soltar aquela gambiarra gloriosa de todo dia e definir a `width` no braço depois de abrir o `Dataset`, mas não é algo a se recomendar por motivos óbvios.

Comment: Achei no forum ou foi um artigo na embarcadeiro de uma procedure de ajustar colunas da dbgrid, até que funciona legal, mas pra um grid que tenha muitas informações não fica legal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso é um BUG que afeta apenas a primeira coluna do DBGrid e da StringGrid. Foi corrigido no RAD Studio 10 Seattle Update 1.

Maiores detalhes no link abaixo:

[RSP-11797 - VCL TStringGrid.ColWidths is broken](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/44619)

Você pode corrigir isso em tempo de execução utilizando o evento AfterOpen de sua tabela, exemplo:

```
    procedure TForm1.ClientDataSet1AfterOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
    begin
      DBGrid1.Columns[0].Width := 200;
    end;
```

Eduardo Belo

Comment: Criei um aplicativo novo com 2 campos no dbgrid , usei sua dica ele ajusta a primeira coluna do tamanho que é colocado e as outras estão ficando do tamanho que era pra ficar. Vou testar em uns grids do meu sistema e verificar..

Obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

1. Salve  `VCL.Grids.pas` na pasta de seu projeto.
2. Encontre `TCustomGrid.ChangeScale`.
3. Comente as linhas 1710 e 1711 e recompile.

Referência:
https://www.nexusdb.com/forums/showthread.php?t=19504

Comment: G.Molina, lembro que este fórum é em português e as perguntas, respostas e comentários devem ser em português.